Complex Roots for Parabolic-- Alternative Method
Lol I am kind of embarrassed how long I was thinking about this-- any help or added insights would be awesome!!!
Let's say we have a problem like:
If it says determine the complex Roots from the graph

Method 1 (no tricks):
Vertex form:
Y = a(x - h)^2 + k
Vertex (h, k) is (-2, 4)
One point (x,y) is (0,8)
Y = a(x-h)^2 + k
8 = a(0+2)^2 + 4
8 = a4 + 4
a = 1
So our equation is:
Y = 1(x+2)^2 + 4 (vertex form)
y = x^2 + 4x + 8 (standard form)
If we find the roots then it will be:
0 = 1(x+2)^2 + 4
-4 = 1(x+2)^2
-4 = (x+2)^2
+/- sqrt(-4) = x + 2
x = -2 +/- 2i
x = -2 +/- 2i
Method 2 (I feel like I am very close. I came up with it on my own (after thinking about it and testing out problems)
In short the x-value will correspond to the x-value of the vertex. And the y value will be the sqrt of the vertex |y| value * i.

I get when we have complex roots-- the determinant will be negative. So the real part will be y = -b/2a (quadratic formula after removing the determinant part). Additionally if you have a quadratic equation in standard form the x-value of the vertex will be x = -b/2a. And so they are both the same and therefore they will have the same x-value.
And the +/- comes from the determinant. Sqrt(b^2 - 4AC)/2A.
So in this case vertex x value was -2 and the y value we will say sqrt(4) * i = 2i
So the complex roots will be -2 +/- 2i
Doing another one:

The parabola equation is x^2 + 4x + 7.
So the complex roots will be:
x = -2 +/- sqrt(3) * i
Likewise with method 2 it would be:
vertex x value was -2 and the imaginary part will be the sqrt of the y value * i, so sqrt(3)* i
x = -2 +/- sqrt(3) * i
Trying a different quadrant graph
This graph is of -x^2 + 4x - 13

Complex roots will be:
x = 2 +/- sqrt(|-9|) i
So:
x = 2 +/- 3i
Questionish:
First off is my method 2-- is it logically sound? Or am I missing something fundamental? I know if I plot a complex number-- x-axis is real and y-axis is imaginary (this is not relevant here though).
So the big thing that I want make sure is correct is "I get when we have complex roots-- the determinant will be negative. So the real part will be x = -b/2a (quadratic formula after removing the determinant part). Additionally if you have a quadratic equation in standard form the x-value of the vertex will be x = -b/2a. And so they are both the same and therefore they will have the same x-value."
In short the x-value will correspond to the x-value of the vertex. And the y value will be the sqrt of the vertex |y| value * i.
Also if the roots were real-- then the vertex x-value will be in between the two roots. This does not apply to complex roots. And because of that-- I'm wondering if this still holds: "And so they are both the same and therefore they will have the same x-value".  This is the part I feel kind of iffy about.
Also the +/- sqrt(|y value of vertex|) we see it works for the examples and we see the idea behind it +/- sqrt of determinant/2A. I just feel iffy about it (hard to explain why), any 2 cents would be appreciated on that. Like why (the algebra behind) would the sqrt of |y| value of the vertex correspond to +/- sqrt of determinant/2A (for a parabola that doesn't cross the x-axis).
Google has the AI Overview-- when you search: "complex roots is the vertex" & "complex roots is the vertex x-value". I didn't want to copy and paste their output. But they often put in quotation themselves "midway" & "halfway"-- vertex x-axis will be between the complex roots. So like for the first problem when the answer was -2 +/- 2i if we average it-- ((-2 + 2i)+(2 - 2i))/2 = 2 (because the +2i & -2i cancel each other out)... I'm pretty sure that's what they are saying from it.
Any insights would be appreciated!!!

Please use MathJax to format your equations.

The quadradic formula is a fine way to find the roots of a quadratic, whether real or complex.
$ax^2+ bx + c = 0 \implies  x = -\frac {b}{2a} \pm \frac {\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$
If the coefficients are real and the roots are complex:
The real part will be $-\frac {b}{2a}$ and will align with the axis of symmetry (and the vertex) of the parabola.
$\frac {\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ determines the imaginary part.
If have the parabola in vertex form $y = a(x-h)^2+k$ (and $a$ and $k$ have the same sign).
The roots will be $h\pm i\sqrt {\frac {k}{a}}$
Does that confirm all of your discoveries, or was there something I missed?

The situation is they don't actually give you the equation just the graph.
I provided the equation to "prove" my idea would work.
Like equation not given just the graph-- graph does not have real roots.
My method you can get the complex root just by looking at the graph.
Complex roots will be x = (x value of the vertex) +/- sqrt(|y| value of vertex) * i
What you have would be dependent on the equation.

The vertex will tell you the real part of the complex root, but you will need a second point to solve for "a" in $y=a(x-h) + k$ to solve for the imaginary part.

If you noticed the 3 cases above this worked
Complex roots
x = (x value of the vertex) +/- sqrt(|y| value of vertex) * i.
Like why (the algebra behind) would +/- sqrt of |y| value of the vertex correspond to +/- sqrt of determinant/2A (for a parabola that doesn't cross the x-axis).
I did a lot more cases-- they all worked.
I couldn't come up with a case where this was not invalid.

I see something else:
All the cases above was (x + # +##i)(x + # - ##i)
But if it was (2x + 3 + 2i)(2x + 3 - 2i) = 4x^2 + 12x + 13
The vertex will be: (-1.5, 4).
2x + 3 = 0... so the x value is -1.5. (x value not obvious to get). Again in my fictional scenario-- equation not given just graph is given.
But the y value still holds sqrt(4) * i = 2i.

Last one: (3x + 3 + 4i)(3x + 3 - 4i) = 9x^2 + 18x + 25
The vertex is: (-1,16)
Now I have doubts about the x-value, where we cannot just look a the the vertex. Because 3x + 3 = 0... so x  = -1. But we can also say x + 1 = 0.
The y value still holds though sqrt(16)*i = 4i

$(3x + 3 + 4i)(3x + 3 - 4i) = 9x^2 + 18x + 25 = 9(x+1)^2 + 16.$  The vertex is $(-1,16)$ the roots are $x= -1\pm \frac {4}{3}i.$  The real part corresponds to the x-coordinate of the vertex.  The imaginary part is $\pm \sqrt {\frac {16}{9}}i$

9x^2 + 18x + 25 would give you the above complex roots.
Maybe that is a limitation of method 2 (visual identify the vertex approach)-- to automatically identify the roots.
Now if a graph is provided and it says explicitly: when factored it will be in the form of (x + a + bi)(x + a - bi) or (x - a + bi)(x - a - bi).
Then method 2 work (I'm wondering why it does). Because if the graph is in that form then:
Complex roots x will be: (x value of the vertex) +/- sqrt(|y| value of vertex) * i. (I cannot come up with an example when this is not true).

Is it because (x + a + bi)(x + a - bi) or (x - a + bi)(x - a - bi) then the a value will always be 1 (why is that)?
Like why in this form: y= (x + a + bi)(x + a - bi)  would it turn into:  y = a(x-h)^2 + k where the (a) value would be locked at 1.
Because in that form then complex roots: h +/- sqrt(k/a) if a is 1 then k is the vertex y-value

I think in this form:
(x + a + bi)(x + a - bi)
Automatically the leading coefficient will be x^2, so going from standard form to vertex form the a value will be 1.
But (3x + a + bi)(3x + a - bi) then the a value will be 9.

This is exactly not an answer, but may be related in a way.
Thinking of the graphs of parabolas with real and complex roots way back after my college days I was pondering in ways similar to yours now, shall share them fwiw. My real motivation it was that all roots real and complex should be plotted to be seen together.
Was thinking.. why not mid-point of real roots center point on x-axis
$$( -b/2a,0 ) $$
of the standard parabola graph $ y= ax^2+bx +c~$ be taken as the center C of a circle,drawing a circle radius $ R=\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ around it so that this parabola when  pushed up by $2R$ so that the extreme vertex can be configured to lie on the same $ x= -b/(2a) $ vertical line leading to both conjugate complex roots.
The y-axis is real for pure real roots, imaginary for complex roots.
The main idea was to use the real $x-y$ plane also as a complex plane accommodating the complex roots as well.
So the 4 points / roots are:
$$\{- \frac{b}{2 a }+ R,- \frac{b}{2 a } - R, - \frac{b}{2 a }+ i \cdot R, - \frac{b}{2 a }- i \cdot R )\}$$
For including the two real, two complex points somewhat unconventionally this way we should satisfy
$$ R=  \frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}{2a}= c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
which simplifies algebraically to the condition :
$$\boxed{ b=2 \sqrt {a c-1}}$$
We can choose any three constants $ (a,b,c)$ arbitrarily.
So the parabola equations are:
$$ (y_1= ax^2+bx+c, y_1= ax^2+bx+c-2R=ax^2+bx-c+b^2/(2 a)) $$
In a particular example let
$$ (a,b,c)=(2,4,5/2)\to R= \frac12 ~$$
$$ y_1= 2x^2+4x+5/2,~y_2= 2x^2+4x+5/2;~ $$

With such a representation you can see that the radical part of real roots.. that plays the chief role in determining the discriminant sign can be shown into the complex plane also when the coefficients are made to
vary in the manner indicated, capturing the associated complex rooted parabola.
